# Node JS upload binary file to another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, binaryfiles

I've got an audio file which I post to a server for translation. I've managed to create a request in postman, but I do not know how to write the file to this server. Below is the code I have got so far:

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {}

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
   });
});
```

`options{}` is filled with method/hostname/port ofcourse. In postman I add "binary" file, but I cannot figger out how to write a file to the request in Node JS.

Comment: I recently recorded this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8COHTGz2cc) tutorial in which I demonstrate how to upload binary files using multer, but guess what the code example I am showing also covers how to upload binary file from one server to another server, check out this file: https://github.com/mInzamamMalik/upload-file-nodejs/blob/master/clients/nodejs-client.js

Answer (score 4):

One solution that would easily fit into your current program without too much work is to make use of the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) module on npm.

The form-data module makes ease of multipart requests in node. The following is a simple example of how to use.

```
var http = require("https");
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs')

var form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', fs.createReadStream('my_audio.file'));

var options = {
  host: 'your.host',
  port: 443,
  method: 'POST',
  // IMPORTANT!
  headers: form.getHeaders()
}

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
   });
});

// Pipe form to request
form.pipe(req);
```

In a "real-world" scenario you would want to do a lot more error checking. Also, there are plenty of other http clients on npm that make this process easy as well (the request module uses form-data BTW). Check out [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) if you are interested.

For sending a binary request the fundamentals are still the same, `req` is a [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams). As such, you can `pipe` data into the stream, or write directly with `req.write(data)`. Here's an example.

```
var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  // ...
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
  }
}

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
   });
});


var audioFile = fs.createReadStream('my_audio.file', { encoding: 'binary' });
audioFile.pipe(req);
```

Note, that if you use the `write` method explicitly `req.write(data)` you must call `req.end()`. Also, the you may want to take a look at the encoding options for Node's `Buffer` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)).

Comment: Thank you for the help. unfortunately, the server I am posting to does not accept form-data, only binary file transfer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution for me

Comment: Thanks "var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);" really worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @undefined, your answer really helped me.

I am posting my solution which worked for me to send file to another server using axios. Ignore the type specifications, I had Typescript enabled for my project.

```
export const fileUpload: RequestHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const chunks: any[] = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    req.on('end', () => {
        const data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        axios.put("ANOTHER_SERVER_URL", data).then((response) => {
            console.log('Success', response);
        }).catch(error => {            
            console.log('Failure', error);
        });
    });
    return res.status(200).json({});
};
```

Thanks, hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the request package on npm.

Install the `request` module from npm:

`npm install request --save`

Then use the request module to send your request.

Have a look at `https://www.npmjs.com/package/request` for details on implementation.

Comment: Give a real example. Right now it is just a comment