# Curl -d vs --data-binary

Tags: node.js, curl, prometheus

Using this [https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway][1] we are trying to push one metric to prometheus.  It seems to require the data in a very specific format.

It works fine when doing their example curl of

```
echo "some_metric 3.14" | curl --data-binary @- http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job
```

Yet doing a curl with -d option fails as missing end of line/file

```
curl -d 'some_metric 3.15\n' http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job
```

I'm trying to understand the difference in behaviour since I believe both are doing POST commands and I need to replicate this --data-binary option in node.js via "request.post" method but I seem to only be able to replicate the curl -d option which doesn't work.

Any suggestions on hints on what the difference is between -d and --data-binary and to do the equivalent to --data-binary from within node.js?

Comment: why are you combining questions here. 
Are you trying to understand the behaviour of ``curl`` command with its different flags?
or are you trying to send a NodeJS POST request to push metrics to push Gateway?

Comment: Your second command doesn't work because `'\n'` in Bash isn't a newline, it's the letter "`n`". You want to use [ANSI C quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html): `curl -d $'some_metric 3.15\n'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From curl man page:

> **--data-ascii**
>
> (HTTP) This is just an alias for -d, --data.
>
> **--data-binary**
>
> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename. Data is posted > in a similar manner as -d, --data does, except that newlines and carriage returns are > > preserved and conversions are never done.
>
> Like -d, --data the default content-type sent to the server is application/x-www-form-> > urlencoded. If you want the data to be treated as arbitrary binary data by the server > then set the content-type to octet-stream: -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".
>
> If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will append data as > described in -d, --data.

Using `@-` will make curl read the filename from **stdin**.

So, basically in your first variant you send a binary file named "some_metric 3.14".
In the second one, you're sending an ascii string "some_metric 3.15\n".

If you want curl to strip new lines before sending, use **--data-ascii** or **-d** option:

`echo "some_metric 3.14" | curl -d @- http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job`

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response.  Any idea how I can get node.js to POST data that matches the --data-binary curl command?  It seems it should just be a case of adding a \n to the data it is POSTing?  The weird thing seems that the \n approach didn't seem to work hence why I'm curious what else it does differently.

Comment: @sradforth, I'm not quite familiar with `NodeJS` but you can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030484/node-js-upload-binary-file-to-another-server 
Also, it'd be helpful if you send a file you're trying to send and a piece of code that does the file upload

Comment: About posting metric into push gateway - do not forget to add "\n" at the end of line. Without this you will get 400 error code.

Comment: @sradforth did you find out how to do it with NodeJS?

Comment: @Antirreni91 were either of you able to figure out how to do it with NodeJS? Very curious about whether its possible.

Answer (score 4):

`-d` (or `--data`) and `--data-binary` are [exactly the same](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_86_0/src/tool_getparam.c#L1617-L1621) if you're just passing a normal value like this:

```
curl --data somekey=somevalue example.com
```

But if you're telling curl to read the value from a file by passing `--data @filename` (or `@-` to read from stdin) like this:

```
curl --data @./some/path/to/a/file.txt example.com
```

then the difference is that `--data` [removes](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_86_0/src/tool_paramhlp.c#L80) all `\n` and `\r` characters in the file, whereas `--data-binary` just [sends](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_86_0/src/tool_getparam.c#L1597) the [file](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_86_0/src/tool_paramhlp.c#L93-L122) as-is.